# Shopify how to create Price Rule through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am new to shopify. Now I want to use shopify API to create a price rule, this is my source code here
I use rails 5.1.4, shopify_app 8.1.0

```
shop_url = "https://api_key:secret@domain/admin"
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
prerequisite_saved_search_ids = [53677883419]
price_rule = ShopifyAPI::PriceRule.new
price_rule.title = "demodemo"
price_rule.target_name = "line_item"
price_rule.target_selection = "all"
price_rule.allocation_method = "across"
price_rule.value_type = "fixed_amount"
price_rule.value = "-10.0"
price_rule.customer_selection = "prerequisite"
price_rule.prerequisite_saved_search_ids = prerequisite_saved_search_ids
price_rule.start_at = Time.now.iso8601
res = price_rule.save
puts res
```

However it always return me false. If anyone has the idea? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Api to create price rule([Shopify Api](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/pricerule#create)). I have used this Api in php and its working fine for me.

I have created App and then use Api key and secret key to generate price rule.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming to this question, one could fetch Price rules as per shopify_app gem for Rails applications as:

First allow your app to access read/write permissions in initializers/shopify.rb file as:

```
config.scope = "read_products, write_products, read_price_rules, write_price_rules"
```

After that you can fetch price rules as:

```
@price_rules = ShopifyAPI::PriceRule.find(:all, params:{id: '4171201931'})
```

And can also create a price rule as:

```
    @create_price_rule = ShopifyAPI::PriceRule.new(
    price_rule: {
        title: "FREESHIPPING2",
        target_type: "shipping_line",
        target_selection: "all",
        allocation_method: "each",
        value_type: "percentage",
        value: "-100.0",
        usage_limit: 20,
        customer_selection: "all",
        prerequisite_subtotal_range: {
          greater_than_or_equal_to: "50.0"
        },
        starts_at: "2017-11-19T17:59:10Z"
    }
)
@create_price_rule.save
```

There are validations involved. Incase you want to check the response, one may inspect it like `@create_price_rule.inspect`

Or even you can delete a PriceRule as:

```
@price_rules = ShopifyAPI::PriceRule.find(:all).first
@price_rules.destroy
@last_price_rule = ShopifyAPI::PriceRule.find(4171860875)
```